# Aurelia app "Hello World" not working at all

Tags: javascript, node.js, sharepoint, typescript, aurelia

I am creating a Sharepoint framework webpart, and I am trying to use Aurelia as my JavaScript framework.

Basically I created a Sharepoint framework webpart, which when created with Yeoman, creates this [folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOW2b.png).

Then my files (just a simple hello world):

app.html

```
<template>
  ${message}
</template>
```

app.js

```
export class App {
  message = 'hello world';
}
```

main.ts

```
import {Aurelia} from 'aurelia-framework';

export function configure(aurelia) {
  aurelia.use
    .standardConfiguration()
    .developmentLogging();

  aurelia.start().then(a => a.setRoot());
}
```

index.html

```
 <div aurelia-app>
    <h1>Loading...</h1>
    <h2> ftw </h2>
    <script src="jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
    <script src="config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('aurelia-bootstrapper');
    </script>

  </div>
```

And the helloworld webpart:

```
import {
  BaseClientSideWebPart,
  IPropertyPaneSettings,
  IWebPartContext,
  PropertyPaneTextField
} from '@microsoft/sp-client-preview';

import styles from './HelloWorld.module.scss';
import * as strings from 'helloWorldStrings';
import { IHelloWorldWebPartProps } from './IHelloWorldWebPartProps';
import { configure } from './main';
import * as systemjs from 'systemjs';
import {Aurelia} from 'aurelia-framework';

export default class HelloWorldWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<IHelloWorldWebPartProps> {

  public constructor(context: IWebPartContext) {
    super(context);
  }

  public render(): void {
    if (this.renderedOnce === false) {
      this.domElement.innerHTML = require('./index.html');
    }
  }

  protected get propertyPaneSettings(): IPropertyPaneSettings {
    return {
      pages: [
        {
          header: {
            description: strings.PropertyPaneDescription
          },
          groups: [
            {
              groupName: strings.BasicGroupName,
              groupFields: [
                PropertyPaneTextField('description', {
                  label: strings.DescriptionFieldLabel
                })
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

The code renders the HTML in the page, but without the message.

I don't see any error in the browser console.

I installed Aurelia with NPM no jspm.  Executing `gulp serve` does not show any compilation error.

I also created a typings file "aurelia.d.ts" in the typings subfolder.

I think that my main problem is in the index.html, as it has a reference to 2 JavaScript files, but I am not sure how to reference them because they are inside the NPM modules folder and I don't think they are deployed when doing `gulp serve`.

And by the way, here's my config.json:

```
{
  "entries": [
    {
      "entry": "./lib/webparts/helloWorld/HelloWorldWebPart.js",
      "manifest": "./src/webparts/helloWorld/HelloWorldWebPart.manifest.json",
      "outputPath": "./dist/hello-world.bundle.js"
    }
  ],
  "externals": {
    "@microsoft/sp-client-base": "node_modules/@microsoft/sp-client-base/dist/sp-client-base.js",
    "@microsoft/sp-client-preview": "node_modules/@microsoft/sp-client-preview/dist/sp-client-preview.js",
    "@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset": "node_modules/@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset/dist/sp-lodash-subset.js",
    "office-ui-fabric-react": "node_modules/office-ui-fabric-react/dist/office-ui-fabric-react.js",
    "react": "node_modules/react/dist/react.min.js",
    "react-dom": "node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.min.js",
    "aurelia": "node_modules/aurelia-framework/dist/aurelia-framework.js",
    "systemjs" : "node_modules/systemjs/dist/systemjs/system.js"
  },
  "localizedResources": {
    "helloWorldStrings": "webparts/helloWorld/loc/{locale}.js"
  }
}
```

Errors in the console:

> FetchProvider.ts:30 GET
>   https://softwares-macbook-pro.local:4321/sites/workbench/_api/Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.SuiteNavData.GetSuiteNavData?v=2&Locale=undefined
>   404 (Not Found)FetchProvider.fetch @
>   FetchProvider.ts:30BasicHttpClient.fetchCore @
>   BasicHttpClient.ts:68HttpClient._fetchWithInstrumentation @
>   HttpClient.ts:183HttpClient.fetch @ HttpClient.ts:141HttpClient.get @
>   HttpClient.ts:154OnPremSuiteNavDataSource.loadData @
>   OnPremSuiteNavDataSource.ts:42SuiteNavManager._loadSuiteNavFromServer
>   @ SuiteNavManager.ts:148SuiteNavManager._getSuiteNavModel @
>   SuiteNavManager.ts:129SuiteNavManager.loadSuiteNav @
>   SuiteNavManager.ts:106(anonymous function) @
>   Shell.ts:164Shell._startApplication @ Shell.ts:145Shell.start @
>   Shell.ts:141(anonymous function) @ SPModuleLoader.ts:178
>   TraceLogger.ts:147 [OnPremSuiteNavDataSource] Failed to retrieve
>   Hybrid SuiteNavData TraceLogger.ts:147 [SuiteNavManager]
>   SuiteNavManager loadData Failed to retrieve Hybrid SuiteNavData
>   FetchProvider.ts:30 POST
>   https://softwares-macbook-pro.local:4321/sites/workbench/_api/contextinfo
>   405 (Method Not Allowed)FetchProvider.fetch @
>   FetchProvider.ts:30DigestCache.fetchDigest @
>   DigestCache.ts:73HttpClient.fetch @ HttpClient.ts:129HttpClient.post @
>   HttpClient.ts:167SPOSuiteNavDataSource.loadData @
>   SPOSuiteNavDataSource.ts:41SuiteNavManager._loadSuiteNavFromServer @
>   SuiteNavManager.ts:153SuiteNavManager._getSuiteNavModel @
>   SuiteNavManager.ts:129SuiteNavManager.loadSuiteNav @
>   SuiteNavManager.ts:106(anonymous function) @
>   Shell.ts:164Shell._startApplication @ Shell.ts:145Shell.start @
>   Shell.ts:141(anonymous function) @ SPModuleLoader.ts:178
>   FetchProvider.ts:30 GET
>   https://softwares-macbook-pro.local:4321/sites/workbench/_api/web/GetClientSideWebParts 404 (Not Found)FetchProvider.fetch @
>   FetchProvider.ts:30BasicHttpClient.fetchCore @
>   BasicHttpClient.ts:68HttpClient._fetchWithInstrumentation @
>   HttpClient.ts:183HttpClient.fetch @ HttpClient.ts:141HttpClient.get @
>   HttpClient.ts:154(anonymous function) @
>   ClientSideWebPartManager.ts:335ServiceScope.whenFinished @
>   ServiceScope.ts:174(anonymous function) @
>   ClientSideWebPartManager.ts:333ClientSideWebPartManager.fetchWebParts
>   @ ClientSideWebPartManager.ts:327CanvasStore._fetchWebParts @
>   CanvasStore.ts:509CanvasStore @ CanvasStore.ts:93Canvas @
>   Canvas.ts:59Page.componentDidMount @ Page.tsx:28target.(anonymous
>   function) @ index.js:153notifyAll @ react.js:869close @
>   react.js:12870closeAll @ react.js:15699perform @
>   react.js:15646batchedMountComponentIntoNode @ react.js:10882perform @
>   react.js:15633batchedUpdates @ react.js:8456batchedUpdates @
>   react.js:13706_renderNewRootComponent @
>   react.js:11076ReactMount__renderNewRootComponent @
>   react.js:12353_renderSubtreeIntoContainer @ react.js:11150render @
>   react.js:11170React_render @ react.js:12353SpWebpartWorkbench.onRender
>   @ spWebpartWorkbench.tsx:44ClientSideApplication.render @
>   ClientSideApplication.ts:83(anonymous function) @
>   Shell.ts:165Shell._startApplication @ Shell.ts:145Shell.start @
>   Shell.ts:141(anonymous function) @ SPModuleLoader.ts:178
>   TraceLogger.ts:147 [SuiteNavManager] SuiteNavManager loadData Failed
>   to retrieve SPO SuiteNavData TraceLogger.ts:145
>   [ClientSideWebPartManager] SyntaxError: Unexpected token C in JSON at
>   position 0TraceLogger._writeToConsole @
>   TraceLogger.ts:145TraceLogger._log @
>   TraceLogger.ts:117TraceLogger.logError @ TraceLogger.ts:42(anonymous
>   function) @ ClientSideWebPartManager.ts:355 TraceLogger.ts:147
>   [ClientSideWebPartManager] Successfully loaded modules for webpart
>   7fb7d3c1-c91b-4038-8e2b-2c7dc5376161 TraceLogger.ts:147
>   [BaseClientSideWebPart] Constructed web part:
>   568966e1-6496-4915-927f-ce874bbe7d27 OnPremSuiteNavDataSource.ts:65
>   Uncaught (in promise) Error: Failed to retrieve Hybrid
>   SuiteNavData(…)OnPremSuiteNavDataSource._logAndThrowSuiteNavLoadingError
>   @ OnPremSuiteNavDataSource.ts:65(anonymous function) @
>   OnPremSuiteNavDataSource.ts:45 Beacon.js:372 Beacon: Logged to
>   UserEngagement with properties:
>   {"EngagementName":"SPPages.SPThemeProvider.loadData.Start","Properties":"{\"appver\":\"\"}","Duration":0,"LogType":0,"ClientTime":1478836974552,"Source":"ClientV2Reliability"}

[image]

Comment: If you change the `${message}` by actual HTML just to test does it display?

Comment: Nope it does not, willing to help me to make it work? should we try offline?

Comment: You installed with NPM, not JSPM, yet you have a config.js file that you're using with SystemJS. Are you sure that your libraries are loading and being bundled? If you didn't install Aurelia through System.JS you would have had to manually configure your config.js to point to your NPM modules.

Comment: yes I did use NPM because JSPM seem to be for standalone aurelia apps, and all samples I found about Sharpeoint Framework its with NPM, so dont really know the difference,  does that command create config.json?  the config.json is created with yoman when first scaffolded, and I guess it uses SystemJS as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without specifying an attribute to the `aurelia-app`, it loads by default `app.html` and `app.js`. So what you'd want to do is change it to:

```
<div aurelia-app="main">
```

So that loads `main.js` and actually starts aurelia.

[Here's a link to the documentation](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/app-configuration-and-startup/1) about bootstrapping aurelia.

Comment: thanks, but that didnt work either, I still have no errors in the console, I wll put this in github to check it out, just gimme some time

Comment: Does ANYTHING even log in the console? Because you're using development logging it should at least show logs from the framework.

Comment: yes, but very difficult to share the logs, I updated the question with 5 errors, at least 4 of them seem to be from sharepoint framework running locally and not from my code, there is one that could be from my code but I am not sure, I will upload a picture now to the quesiton.

Comment: upload done, please check if this gives any insights

Comment: So basically you are only running `yo @microsoft/sharepoint` and `gulp serve` and you get these errors?

Comment: if you give me an email, I can send you the entire folder via wetransfer

Comment: I uploaded it here: https://github.com/levalencia/SharepointFrameworkCodeSamples/tree/master/spfsamplewithaureliatest2

Comment: I'll look at it tomorrow. I haven't try the Sharepoint framework yet, so it's a new one for me. I'll see if I can come up with what went wrong.

Comment: check my blog for tutorials on that, just integrating with aurelia its difficult and no doc available yet.  www.luisevalencia.com